# Не выводятся последние изображения на странице CMS WP

Tags: wordpress

Не выводятся изображения последних постов в wp.
В чём проблема?

```
  <div class="new-posts">
  <?php
      $recent_posts = wp_get_recent_posts(3);
      foreach($recent_posts as $post){
        echo '<div class="new-post"><a href="' . get_permalink($post["ID"]) . '" title="'.$post["post_title"].'" >'; ?>   
      <img src="<?php wp_get_recent_posts($post["ID"]); ?>" alt="">
      <?php echo '</a><a class="link" href="' . get_permalink($post["ID"]) . '" title="'.$post["post_title"].'" >' .   $post["post_title"].'</a></div>';}?>
      </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Проблема в том, что вы пытаетесь получить ссылку на изображение функцией `wp_get_recent_posts()`. Используйте, например, функцию `get_the_post_thumbnail_url()`

```
<img src="<?php echo get_the_post_thumbnail_url($post["ID"]); ?>" alt="">
```